# API Level 21 app searching for API Level 23 resource after installing google play services

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

Im developing an app that requires google maps, I follow the google tutorials [by adding a activity map in android studio](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) but right after the activity got created, downloaded the google play services dependency packge and the build finish, i got this error:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

I opened the resource and I noticed that is requesting `v23\values-v23.xml` resource and I am not using api level 23 in my app. This is my graddle config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "?"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.5-beta"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
}
```

Why is now my proyect asking for this resource? Does google play services has something to do with this? How can i fixed?

Comment: try reducing com.google.android.gms:play-services to 8.4.0

Comment: Nothing changed, the same error.

Comment: You can try setting the compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'. If you are targeting the sdk of your app to 21. Also encountered the same issue, I removed the 6.0 in the SDK Platform, removed any related SDK tools to level 23 but still encountering the same problem

Comment: @Mr.Rebot We dont intent to use sdk 23, our target version is 21. What else do you suggest? We still stuck with this error.

Comment: @Misters, what I mean is that you will have to use the compileSdkVersion 23 for updated permissions and libraries your app can or use but still make your targetSdk as level 21. I have tested it, I hope it works for you too.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot sorry i take this long to answers. If I change compileSdkVersion to 23, will the system prompt the user to allow the app to write/read files from the device at runtime?

Comment: If you want a [system prompt](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) use targetSdk to 23. API level 23 introduces a new permissions model, where users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime and it is not available in [API level 21](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117431/discussion-between-misters-and-mr-rebot).