# google maps v2 using Android Api 19

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want to work with Google Maps v2 using `API Level 19`, can someone help me with where to start?

I´d like to know what relation there is between each version of Android and the version of Google Play services, and which of them I can use.

Comment: I'm not sure API 19 should conflict with the latest Google play services...  https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html

Comment: Just in case, use Google Play Service 8.3.0. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383369/api-level-21-app-searching-for-api-level-23-resource-after-installing-google-pla) previous SO question encountered an error when he is using `compileSdkVersion 21` with Google Play Service 9.0.2. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for all, am using API 23 with Google_play_services_version 7095000  it works fine.